# Experimenting with and inspecting newtypes in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm experimenting with `newtypes` and attempting to expose a `newtype F` to users of `Lib`. I've written a simple use case example below where I want to inspect the `newtype F` after applying `someFunc`.

However the compiler is pointing out that what I think is a `F Double` is actually a `F (Double -> Double)` and consequently there's no Show instance for it i.e., *No instance for (Show (Double -> Double)) arising from a use of ‘show’ (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)*

I get it but I'm having difficulty thinking of how to construct a show instance for this.  Can anyone think of an approach that would preserve my `newtype F`, while hiding `F'` and `someFunc'` from users of this library?

```
-- Lib.hs    
module Lib
  ( someFunc
  , F(..)
  ) where

newtype F a = F (a -> Double)
type F' a = a -> Double

someFunc :: Double -> Double -> F Double
someFunc a b = F (\x -> someFunc' a b x)

someFunc' :: Double -> Double -> F' Double
someFunc' a b x = a * x + b

-- Main.hs
module Main where

import Prelude
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Lib

foo :: Double -> F Double
foo x = someFunc 1.0 2.0

inspectFoo :: F Double -> String
inspectFoo (F x) = "F(" <> show x <> ")"

main :: IO ()
main = print . inspectFoo $ foo 2.0
```

Comment: You have wrong type of `someFunc'`. It should be `someFunc' :: Double -> Double -> Double -> F' Double`

Comment: No, that type is correct in OP's code @Shersh

Comment: Or, indeed. Mismatched `F` with `F'` because was in hurry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clarify this situation by writing it like

```
newtype F a = MakeF (a -> Double)
```

Pattern matching on MakeF like

```
func :: F SomeType -> ...
func (MakeF g) = ...
```

Will give `g :: SomeType -> Double`. A value of type `F a` is isomorphic to a function of type `a -> Double`, so the same set of operations is possible on each.

The real answer here is that it is impossible to `Show` a function in a meaningful way. Since you can't `Show` `a -> Double`, you can't `Show` `F a`.